# Skip the rest of rx-java pipeline without throwing exception

Tags: java, kotlin, project-reactor

I was wondering what is the best way to skip the execution of the rest of the pipeline if something happens in a step.

Lets assume I have a long pipeline like this (kotlin). I would like to avoid using expensive resource of barAsync when fooAsnyc returns something problematic. (Not exception).

```
fun longAsyncCalculation(): Mono<CalculationResponse> {
    return Mono.just(Context())
       .flatMap { context ->
           fooAsync(context)
       }.flatMap { context ->
           barAsync(context)
       }.map { context ->
           createResponse(context)
       }
}
```

I can throw an exception of course but I would like to avoid controlling the program flow with exceptions.

Also I would like to avoid checking the context in every step of the pipeline like this:

```
...
.flatMap { context ->
  if(context.hasError) {
    Mono.just(...)
  } else {
    doTheRealAsyncCall()
  }
}.flatMap { context -> 
...
```

Is there way to continue on the error path without throwing an exception? I guess not because the rx error handling methods always work with Throwable.

Any good practices would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: I would be shocked if you could do this without exceptions.

Comment: Try composing onto `fooAsync` inside `flatMap`.